# Propagating null within OneWayBind in ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I have pretty simple `ReactiveObject` ViewModel, where properties are `ReactiveObject`s.

In view I have following binding:

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
                 vm => vm.CurrentEditor.SelectedTreeViewItem.ItemTitle,
                 v => v.CurrentSelectionImage.ToolTip);
```

Is it possible to set Tooltip to `null` when `CurrentEditor` becomes `null`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior as per the [docs](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-any/#whenany-will-not-propagate-nullreferenceexceptions-within-the-watched-expression).

There may be a better way to achieve it, but at the very least you can use WhenAnyValue and bind it to both CurrentEditor *and* CurrentEditor.SelectedTreeViewItem.ItemTitle:

```
ViewModel.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.CurrentEditor,
                       vm => vm.CurrentEditor.SelectedTreeViewItem.ItemTitle,
                       (ce, title) => ce == null ? null : title)
         .BindTo(this, v => v.CurrentSelectionImage.ToolTip);
```

Comment: I am doing it that way at the moment, but sometimes I get 4 elements in VhenAnyValue:)